# scikit learn Grid Cross Validation returning incorrect mean

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I used the GridCV to do cross validation across k folds to tune my hyper parameters. The mean results which should have been mean over individual folds is wrong in my results attribute "cv_results_". Following is my code for same:

```
gscv = GridSearchCV(n_jobs=n_jobs,cv=train_test_iterable, estimator=pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, 
                verbose=10, scoring=['accuracy', 'precision','recall','f1'], refit='f1', 
                    return_train_score=return_train_score, error_score=error_score,
                   )
gscv.fit(X,Y)
gscv.cv_results_
```

The cv_results_ contains following json(displayed as table)

```
    mean_test_f1    split0_test_f1  split1_test_f1  Actual Mean
    0.934310796     0.935603198     0.933665455     0.934634326
    0.931279716     0.908430118     0.942689316     0.925559717
    0.927683609     0.912005672     0.935512149     0.923758911
    0.680908006     0.741198823     0.650802701     0.696000762
    0.680908006     0.741198823     0.650802701     0.696000762
    0.646005028     0.684483208     0.626791532     0.65563737
    0.840273248     0.847484083     0.836672627     0.842078355
    0.837160828     0.847484083     0.832006068     0.839745075
    0.833637        0.842109375     0.829406448     0.835757911
```

You can see above: the "mean_test_f1" is not the mean of two folds "split0_test_f1", "split1_test_f1". Actual mean is the last column.

Note: F1 means the f1-score.

Did anyone face similar issues?

Answer (score 1):

I think what your seeing is a weighed mean not a direct average.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `iid=False` in `GridSearchCV(...)` and compare.

According to documentation:

> ```
> iid : boolean, default=True
>
>     If True, the data is assumed to be identically distributed across 
>     the folds, and the loss minimized is the total loss per sample,
>     and not the mean loss across the folds.
> ```

So when `iid` is True (by default), averaging of test scores include a weight as specified [here in source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L725):

```
    _store('test_%s' % scorer_name, test_scores[scorer_name],
                   splits=True, rank=True,
                   weights=test_sample_counts if iid else None)
```

Please note that train scores are not affected by it, so also cross-check the mean of train scores.